# Error when upload file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, java-ee-7

```
  if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request))  // ako je forma multipart ulazimo u naredbu
           {
               FileItemFactory factory=new DiskFileItemFactory();
               ServletFileUpload upload=new ServletFileUpload(factory);

               List items=upload.parseRequest(request);
               Iterator iterator=items.iterator();

               while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                   FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();
                   if (!item.isFormField())
                   {
                       out.print("Velicina fajla je: "+item.getSize());
                   }
               }
           }
```

[image]
I try to upload file on the server over html form,where server(jsp page) parse them and read size of file and back answer to client the size of the file.But error in app shows when selected file on disk and clicked submit button.

Comment: I think it's a better idea to post code rather than screenshots :-) , so can you please post your index.jsp !

Comment: better? @AbelRoussi

Comment: Not too much! anyway, the error page indicate that you have some problems on line 17 of your index.jsp page, what did line 17 contains?

Comment: There begins scriplet...

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you have some JAR files missing from your classpath. Probably commons-fileupload-.jar at a minimum.

Comment: Problem is solved.  :)